# AWS Pinpoint - get Campaign delivery counts - Messages sent/Delivered by API/CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to find out how to get Campaign delivery counts - Messages sent by specific AWS Pinpoint campaign per date using API or AWS CLI command but I can't find any documentation for helping with it.

I tried multiple AWS CLI command for it but none of them helped me getting the actual number.
I only was able to fetch the successful percentage.

```
aws pinpoint get-campaign-date-range-kpi --profile=<profile_name> --application-id <application_id> --campaign-id '<campaign_id>' --kpi-name 'successful-delivery-rate-grouped-by-date'
```